# too few arguments to function 'void setColor(int, int, int)'

Tags: arduino, arguments

When I put "c" inside `setColor(c);`

it tells me:

`error: too few arguments to function 'void setColor(int, int, int)'`.

I understand that I should put 3 arguments. What I don't understand is that the serial is correctly displaying the 3 arguments (255, 000, 000) so why it  keeps telling me this error. What am I doing wrong ?

```
int rPin = 11;
int gPin = 9;
int bPin = 10;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(rPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(gPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(bPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            delay(100);
            while (Serial.available() > 0) {
                char c = Serial.read(); // serial will display an rgb code, for exemple: 255, 000, 000 (red color) 
                setColor(c);
            }
        }
}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
    analogWrite(rPin, red);
    analogWrite(gPin, green);
    analogWrite(bPin, blue);
}
```

Comment: I do not code in C, but you will be getting string/list and you have to pass the arguments one by one.

Comment: In case you get a list, do `setColor(c[0], c[1], c[2])` or however the correct syntax is

Comment: In case you get a string, you will have to split up the string into a list with a function, and then pass the arguments one by one

Comment: If you do not want to pass the arguments one by one, modify the void setColor function to get a list, and then use the list inside the void

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As your error told you, `setColor(int red, int green, int blue)` requires 3 arguments that you should pass at the same time.

The problem is that you get your arguments from reading the `Serial` port which are not `int`s but the ASCII values of the characters you write, i.e. `0 = 48`.

So you need to use `Serial.parseInt()` to get the actual values you want.

Here is what your code should look like.

```
int rPin = 11;
int gPin = 9;
int bPin = 10;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(rPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(gPin, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(bPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop() {
    if (Serial.available() > 0) {
            delay(100);

            while (Serial.available() > 0) {

            // look for the next valid integer in the incoming serial stream:
            int red = Serial.parseInt(); 
            // do it again:
            int green = Serial.parseInt(); 
            // do it again:
            int blue = Serial.parseInt(); 

            // look for the newline. That's the end of your sentence:
            if (Serial.read() == '\n') {
                // constrain the values to 0 - 255
                red = 255 - constrain(red, 0, 255);
                green = 255 - constrain(green, 0, 255);
                blue = 255 - constrain(blue, 0, 255);

                setColor(red, green, blue);

            }
        }
}

void setColor(int red, int green, int blue) {
    analogWrite(rPin, red);
    analogWrite(gPin, green);
    analogWrite(bPin, blue);
}
```